# Div moving down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to animate a so that when the iframe source changes it is hidden and then shown again. The problem is that when the `show` is triggered, my div moves down. I really have no idea what should I do, I am pretty sure the css is the problem. My code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RPxFs/

Click on the black part to change the source, you will see 'page not found' in the iframe but anyway you'll see what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is for an excesive width in the iframe container. Quick solution pass with reduce `padding-left` in your `#frame_div` ;)

Comment: Why not use jQuery toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

`$('#foo').toggle(showOrHide);` is the same as `if ( showOrHide == true ) {
  $('#foo').show();
} else if ( showOrHide == false ) {
  $('#foo').hide();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it goes down because the width is overlapping.

div navigation and div frame_div

try to decrease the width percentage of frame_div to 79% and remove div frame_div styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/RPxFs/7/

```
<div src="save.php" id="frame_div" >
#frame_div{
    float: left;
    height: 90%;
    width: 79%;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RPxFs/19/ look here, I've just added

```
 position: absolute;
```

for navigation and it works perfect

Comment: it still goes down. and I need it to be 500px

Comment: @wm.p1us position:absolute will make the animation not work anymore, I tried it

Comment: I change things in previous link. in answer animation works fine

Comment: Yep, it does. It moves a little bit to right, but it's a good answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you give the containing div a fixed width that will be enough to hold both the navigation and the iframe then they should sit side by side.

I have chosen `width: 800px;`

See my fiddle for how I laid it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/RPxFs/

Comment: I instead decreased the width of the div, the container needs to be at that size. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For solution to this remove this attribute     **float: left;** from below iframe container.

```
#frame_div {
    border-right: 1px solid #999999;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
}
```

if you need to add **float attribute** in that case you need to provide total with of what area left container + iframe container covers in order to appear them side by side.

Here is jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/RPxFs/20/